# How do i implement RemoteObject in a foreign class?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, remoteobject

Heres the code:

```
public class Schem
{
    public var info:String="";      

    public function Schem()
    {
    }

    public function loadCurrentSchem():void
    {
        var ro:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("Hibernatetest");
        ro.endpoint = "http://Jesus/blazeds/messagebroker/amf";
        ro.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,onResult);
        ro.getCells();
        info = info + "Loader called ... \n";




    }

    public function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        var array:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;
        info = info + "Schemlength = " + String(array.length)+ "\n";
    }


    private function onFault(event:FaultEvent):void
    {
        info = info + "Errorhandler Called";
    }
    //Eventhandlers


    //Getters, Setters
}
```

Unfortunatly, its doesnt reach the eventHandler, when i call the loadCurrentSchem() function. Whats wrong?

This is how i call the class:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import argoseye.main.Golem;
        import argoseye.main.Schem;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
        import mx.rpc.Responder;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var schem:Schem = new Schem();
            schem.loadCurrentSchem();
            textfeld.text = schem.info;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

There.

Comment: Are you sure your endpoint is getting hit?

Comment: Yes I am. For two reasons. First: This very code works in the application script-tag perfectly, and second: The BlazeDS Console counts an successfull call.

Comment: Did you tried to subscribe to the `fault` event too? Maybe result handler doesn't invoke because of some fault which you doesn't listen at all?

Comment: Just did it, and, as expected, nothing. I dont understand the difference...it should work in a serpate class, to, shouldnt it?

Comment: In future use debugger breakpoints or `trace()` statements to make sure some method is calling or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you haven't proper made sure the result handler called correctly. The thing is that when you use:

```
textfeld.text = schem.info;
```

you've set the value of:

```
info = info + "Loader called ... \n";
```

as a text of the text field and this value isn't changed in a result handler.

You can resolve this issue at least two ways:

- Extend your `Schem` class from `EventDispatcher` and place events metadata there.

The class:

```
[Event(name="result", type="mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent")]
[Event(name="fault", type="mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent")]
public class Schem extends EventDispatcher
{
    public var info:String="";      

    public function Schem()
    {
    }

    public function loadCurrentSchem():void
    {
        var ro:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("Hibernatetest");
        ro.endpoint = "http://Jesus/blazeds/messagebroker/amf";
        ro.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,onResult);
        ro.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,onFault);
        ro.getCells();
        info += "Loader called ... \n";




    }

    private function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        var array:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;
        info += "Schemlength = " + String(array.length)+ "\n";
        dispatchEvent(event);
    }


    private function onFault(event:FaultEvent):void
    {
        info += "Errorhandler Called";
        dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    //Eventhandlers


    //Getters, Setters
}
```

Then in your MXML class:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import argoseye.main.Golem;
        import argoseye.main.Schem;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
        import mx.rpc.Responder;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var schem:Schem = new Schem();
            schem.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,onResult);
            schem.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,onFault);
            schem.loadCurrentSchem();
            textfeld.text = schem.info;

        }

    private function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        textfeld.text = event.currentTarget.info;
    }

    private function onFault(event:FaultEvent):void
    {
        textfeld.text = event.currentTarget.info;
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

- The second way is to use data binding.

`Schem` class:

```
public class Schem
{
    [Bindable]
    public var info:String="";      

    public function Schem()
    {
    }

    public function loadCurrentSchem():void
    {
        var ro:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("Hibernatetest");
        ro.endpoint = "http://Jesus/blazeds/messagebroker/amf";
        ro.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,onResult);
        ro.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,onFault);
        ro.getCells();
        info += "Loader called ... \n";
    }

    private function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        var array:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;
        info += "Schemlength = " + String(array.length)+ "\n";
    }


    private function onFault(event:FaultEvent):void
    {
        info += "Errorhandler Called";
    }
    //Eventhandlers


    //Getters, Setters
}
```

And in MXML:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import argoseye.main.Golem;
        import argoseye.main.Schem;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
        import mx.rpc.Responder;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

        [Bindable]
        private var schem:Schem;

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            schem = new Schem();
            schem.loadCurrentSchem();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Label id="textfeld" text="{schem.info}" />
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It helped indeed. Using your method i found out that my class acts quite functional and the problem is passing the results to other classes. I will try a different approach to do this. (Binding)